# add columns according to the rule

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this

```
df = data.frame('a_1' = c(1,0,0), 'b_1' = c(1,0,0), 'c_1' = c(1,0,0), 
           'a_2' = c(0,1,0), 'b_2' = c(0,1,0), 'c_2' = c(0,1,0))
```

I want to get

```
> df
  a b c
1 1 1 1
2 1 1 1
3 0 0 0
```

Of course I can do

```
df$a = df$a_1+df$a_2
df$b = df$b_1+df$b_2
df$c = df$c_1+df$c_2
```

and drop redundant columns. But in the real dataset more columns and this way will take a long time. Is there a faster way?I have to add by 'name' not '_number'

Comment: How does the structure of the real dataset look? Are the names similar, are there always exactly two variables which should be combined?

Comment: @LAP  the real dataset looks as I showed "name" and "_number". Names are the same number is not present

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to strip the names from their `_.*` part and add the ones that match, i.e.

```
sapply(unique(sub('_.*', '', names(df))), function(i) rowSums(df[grepl(i, names(df))]))
```

which gives,

> ```
>      a b c
> [1,] 1 1 1
> [2,] 1 1 1
> [3,] 0 0 0
> ```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, a simple

```
df1 <- mapply(`+`, df[1:3], df[4:6])

> df1
     a_1 b_1 c_1
[1,]   1   1   1
[2,]   1   1   1
[3,]   0   0   0
```

would do the trick. Is your real data in a comparable format?

---

Edit: As @Sotos correctly stated, simply using

```
df1 <- df[1:3]+df[4:6]
```

would be enough.

Comment: FYI that is the same as `df[1:3] + df[4:6]`. No need for `mapply`. The sign `+` is vectorized